# How to fetch output of command into a variable?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, rhel

I am trying to run a command and storing the values in a list

```
list = `sed -n 's/^abc//p' /etc/filename`
```

I am getting an error `command not found` while running the above command.

However, when I directly run the `sed -n 's/^abc//p' /etc/filename` command, the output is coming fine as below:

```
abc01 abc02 abc03
```

Comment: Remove spaces from around `=`, ``list=$(sed -n 's/^abc//p' /etc/filename)``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
list="$(sed -n 's/^abc//p' /etc/filename)"
```

There must be no spaces after variable declaration and equals sign. Also, quoting your variables is important.

Comment: Quoting is indeed good practice, but in the presented case it is not needed.